# File Triggered Automation picking up old files

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I am setting up a File Triggered Automation with a name starts with 'Contacts'. The files come across with a date stamp 'Contacts20160831.txt'. When I drop a file the import works correctly. If I drop a file the following day 'Contacts20160901.txt' the 1st file gets processed.

1. Do I need to use a Substitution String for the date 'Contacts%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%.txt'?
2. I thought I remembered a setting to delete the file after processing, but I can't find this anywhere.
3. Any better suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't using the correct Personalization String. I used %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% and it processes correctly the dropped file.

Comment: Does this still work? Because FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER isn't working for me now, and has also mysteriously disappeared from the documentation.